# Change Font Size from Admin Panel Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to change the frontend font size from the admin panel in Laravel. Suppose there is a

```html
<h2 class="intro">Introduction to PHP...?? </h2>

in style.css-->>>>

.intro{
   font-size:20px;
}
```

I want this font size dynamic from admin panel by catching the class. If i need 25px i use that or any size I need I will use that.

How can I do that in laravel??? Give me some suggestions to step up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use something like this:

Save a file named **style.php** in the path where the asset files are located. Then use in your base blade file like this:

```
<link href="{{ asset('path/style.php') . '?fontSize=' . $fontSize }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The **fontSize** variable is the font size you want to use.

And use in **style.php**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:text/css");
?>
.intro {
   font-size: <?= $_GET['fontSize'] ?>;
}
```

Comment: I want to use 3 types of font size. In this case how can I use the styleshett link and pass different size

Comment: You can link the file like this: `{{ asset('path/style.php') . '?fontSize=' . $fontSize . '&fontSize2=' . $fontSize2 . '&fontSize3=' . $fontSize3 }}` and catch there: `$_GET['fontSize2']` etc.

Comment: okay, from where I get fontsize1, fontsize2, ............. is it from the controller??? 

$fontSize1 =  $setting_data->mbl_heading_font;
        
        return view('frontend.index', compact('setting_data', 'info','portfolio','skills', 'fontSize1'));

Comment: Yes, you can get it that way. Also in `AppServiceProvider` you can send with `view()->composer()` to the view.

Comment: I have use by the way you suggest but not worked

Comment: I think you are having problems sending the data. Pls read: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#view-composers I used this suggested way and it works.

Comment: Why did you think it didn't work for you? Give some more details.

Comment: <link href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/frontend/css/style.php?fontSize1=59px" rel="stylesheet">

I am getting the dynamic value ,,,,,,,,, but in h1 tag with that class style is not added!

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? Try to open the URL in the browser. What did you see?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting end of file in C:\All Programming\Laravel\portfolio-of-navid-hasnain\public\frontend\css\style.php on line 4

Style.php as belows:

<?php
header("Content-Type:text/css");

.intro {
   font-size: <?= $_GET['fontSize1'] ?>;
}

Comment: Add to the end of the `style.php` file: `?>`. And can you show me the inside of the **style.php** file?

Comment: header("Content-Type:text/css");

.intro {
   font-size: <?= $_GET['fontSize1'] ?>;
}



This code is inside php tag

Comment: Can u try this: `<?php header("Content-Type:text/css"); .intro { font-size: <?php echo strval($_GET['fontSize1']) ?>; } ?>`

Comment: not working, before class the dot is the error, ------------------>>> http://127.0.0.1:8000/frontend/css/style.php?fontSize1=59px

Comment: Pls try this, sorry: `<?php
header("Content-Type:text/css");
?>
.intro { font-size: <?php echo strval($_GET['fontSize1']) ?>; } `

Comment: Hello, Can you please have a look at this,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74345785/insert-multiple-rows-in-laravel-image-upload-issues

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be via Javascript and your controller:

In your controller, just pass a variable called `$fontSize` to your view file. The with JavaScript, get the element by the class name and set the CSS `font-size` property to whatever value your `$fontSize` variable has like this:

```
<script>
let h2Item = document.querySelector('.intro');
h2Item.style.fontSize = '{{ $fontSize }}'
</script>
```

Remember that the variable you are passing from your controller should not just be an integer, rather it should be something like `20px` `30px` `2em` etcetera.

Comment: In responsive design, how can it be used??

Comment: @MD.RONYAHMED By that how do you mean?

Comment: I mean that, I want to change the font only in responsive design like mobile device. in that case I need to pass specific font variable to responsive.css. How can I do that?

Comment: Okay. You can just use ```CSS``` media queries to achieve this.